# How do i allow filepicker.js to only allow to upload images& pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, filepicker

I am trying to use filepicker.js to only allow images/pdf to be uploaded
How do i do that please help

```
<input type="filepicker-dragdrop"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
filepicker.setKey('AqaKfUG8HTrO7EehqYXZUz');
</script>
```

This is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cainmodyo/Sn4QM/)

Answer (score 1):

See [Filepicker documentation](https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file-ingestion/javascript-api/pick)

```
{mimetypes: ['image/*', 'application/pdf']}

or
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot for replying, but still it allows to upload other files too

Answer (score 1):

data-fp-mimetypes attribute is to be used

```
<input data-fp-mimetypes="image/*"  type="filepicker-dragdrop" >
```